# Triple Integral to find volume of solid

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, volume

[image]

Can someone tell me what the bounds of the triple integral would be? I am confused as to how to start the problem.

**The previous integral I had was wrong so I am editing the post.
I now think the integral would go from 0 to 2 for the outermost integral dx, then 0 to 2 for dy, and 0 to square root of y for dz the innermost integral.

Comment: Generally, it is good to try to give an explanation of your thought process/attempts for elementary questions like this.

Comment: Sorry! I edited the question with what I think are the bounds.

Comment: You have to think carefully about how the two interesting surfaces interact. If you do the integral with $dz$ on the inside, you will almost surely need to split the integral into two pieces. I recommend you do the integration *carefully* in the order $dy\,dx\,dz$.

Comment: When doing it in that order would the dy bounds be from 0 to z^2? and then x bounds from 0 to 2-z-z^2? I am unsure of what the z bounds would end at though.

Comment: To elaborate on what I just said, if you do the order $dz\,dy\,dx$, then you have to decide when $y=z^2$ is higher/lower than $z=2-x-y$.  That is awkward because you are forced to take square roots. And you will have to split the triangle in the $xy$-plane into two pieces — one on which the first graph is the top, the other on which the second graph is the top.

Comment: Your new $x$ bound is good. But $y$ is incorrect. So where does the parabola $x=2-z-z^2$ intersect $z$-axis? You have to use *both* surfaces to limit $y$. You can't keep ignoring one of them :P

Comment: Oh! So the y bounds would be from z^2 to 2-x-z? Also thank you for being patient with me!

Comment: There you go. This is a tricky problem. The point is that *those* two surfaces determine the whole problem. We need to have the region where we are *between* them. [You might look at some of my lectures on setting up multiple integrals among the YouTube videos linked in my profile. We did a couple that were tricky like this.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quanto's posted answer illustrates the point I made in comments. One should choose the order of integration judiciously to make one's life easier. (Otherwise, one may have to split into two, three, or — gulp — more regions.)
In this case, because the two determining surfaces are $y=z^2$ and $y=2-x-z$, it makes sense to project onto the $xz$-plane and integrate with $dy$ innermost.

The two surfaces intersect when $x=2-z-z^2$. Thus, this parabola and the $x$- and $z$-axes determine the region in the $xz$-plane over which the 3-D region lies. This parabola intersects the $x$-axis at $(2,0,0)$ and the $z$-axis at $(0,0,1)$. Thus, we obtain the iterated integral
$$\int_0^1\int_0^{2-z-z^2}\int_{z^2}^{2-x-z} dy\,dx\,dz.$$
(You should convince yourself that to be in the region determined in the problem, a line parallel to the $y$-axis for fixed $(x,z)$ enters the region at $y=z^2$ and exits at $y=2-x-z$. I.e., thinking of $y$ as "height," the surface $y=z^2$ is the lower surface and the surface $y=2-x-z$ is the higher. In the picture drawn, the first is leftmost and the second is rightmost.)

Answer (score 1):

[image]
Note that the integration region in the $xy$-plane consists of three parts, as indicated by I, II and III in the diagram. Thus, the volume integral can be expressed as,

$$\int_0^1 \int_0^{2-y-\sqrt y} \sqrt y \> dxdy 
+ \int_0^1\int_{2-y-\sqrt y}^{2-y}(2-x-y)dxdy
+ \int_1^2\int_{0}^{2-y}(2-x-y)dxdy$$